# Cloudera Hadoop VM 5.10 - find HDFS path?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Installed Cloudera VM and loaded data file into HDFS. The command "hadoop fs -ls / " help me to verify the data in hdfs. But want to know the physical location where it is residing ?

any suggestion would help .

Comment: Physically went this location /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/data ( the configuration configured in dfs.datanode.data.dir name. Getting permission denied. any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical data is not meant to be readable by a non HDFS superuser account.

Also, it's not meant to be readable as plain text (or whatever you uploaded) by any non HDFS process. The physical location stores the HDFS blocks of the original file.

You can always find the physical disk mount points in the `hdfs-site.xml` configuration file at `dfs.datanode.data.dir`. The namenode data directory is also important, though.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 . Would like to know\see how the file is splitting the data if it is size more than 128 mb\64 mb.. is there any other we see the visually ?

Comment: Visually? Not really. But the number of map tasks created directly corresponds to the number of input splits. (assuming that the input data can be split)